# R programming - How do I extract the following from the string given using gregexpr?

Tags: r, regex

Given the following string, how can I extract out the email address?
The email addresses that I want to extract are enclosed specifically by **<> wrote:**

```
egstring = 'blah blah blah <taylor_swift@gmail.com> wrote: blah blah blah'
```

The following is what I have attempted so far.

```
pos = gregexpr('(?<=(\\<))([a-z0-9.]+\\@[a-z0-9.]+)(?=(\\>\\swrote\\:))',egstring,perl=TRUE)[[1]]
```

What I want to achieve:

```
"taylor_swift@gmail.com"
```

What I got:

```
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
attr(,"capture.start")

[1,] -1 -1 -1
attr(,"capture.length")

[1,] -1 -1 -1
attr(,"capture.names")
[1] "" "" ""
```

I couldn't figure out what went wrong. :/

Comment: Are all the email addresses in your data going to be enclosed in tags `<>` like that? Because that makes things much simpler.

Comment: @Marius Not all of them are but the ones that I want to extract out are enclosed specifically by `<> wrote:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gsub() this works:

```
 gsub(".*<(.*)>.*", "\\1", egstring)
```

Comment: Hmm.. This works for this particular case but I don't quite understand how this works, could you explain it to me? What does `'\\1'` represents? From what I know `gsub` will replace the pattern in the first parameter with the string in the second parameter that is found in `egstring`.

Comment: It is the backreference for capturing the first group that was within the (.*) We use \\ to escape the \ in \1

Comment: Ahh... I see!! As the email addresses that I want to extract are enclosed specifically by `<> wrote:`, I modified the code a little but I wasn't able to extract the email address successfully. The following is what I've done. `gsub(".*<(.*)>(\\swrote\\:)", "\\1", egstring)`

Comment: You could try this - gsub(".*<(.*)>\\s+wrote:.*", "\\1", egstring)

Comment: Alright! Thank you!! :) 
May I also ask what is the significance of including `+` after `\\s`? Since we're only expecting one space after `>`, is it alright to just exclude the `+`? I tried running the code without `+` and the result returned is the same. I'm pretty new to the regular expressions on R so pardon me.

Comment: `+` means "one or more of the previous item", so if you know there is exactly one space, you can remove the `+`.

Comment: For more on regular expressions in R http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html